# Uniform initialization of iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, uniform-initialization

I am very new to C++11 and there is a problem with iterators and uniform initialization, which I do not understand.

Consider the following example, which does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> t{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto iter{t.begin()};                   

    for (; iter != t.end(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In line 6 a vector is initialized using uniform initialization. In line 7 I try to do the same with an iterator. It does not work. Changing line 7 to `auto iter = t.begin()` is ok. I know I could simply use "range based for" for this, but the question is: Why does uniform initialization not work with iterators but is fine with basic types, like `int i{0};` ?

Comment: BTW `auto iter{t.begin()};` is fine, it's what's later that causes the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use an initializer-list as the initializer with `auto`, the variable declared is deduced as an initializer list. In other words, `iter` is declared as `std::initializer_list<vector<int>::iterator>`, and not `vector<int>::iterator` as you might expect.

Changing it to `auto iter = t.begin()` is the best way to proceed.

Comment: Note that this might change [in the future](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3912.html). The proposed (breaking) change is that *direct-list-initialization* will never deduce `initializer_list`.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 has a special rule for `auto` and braced initialization which is inferred to `std::initializer_list`. In your case your choices are one of the following:

```
auto iter(t.begin());
auto iter = t.begin();
```

The behavior is described at:

> #### §7.1.6.4/7 `auto` specifier [dcl.spec.auto]
>
> **Let T be the declared type of the variable** or return type of the function. If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. If the deduction is for a return statement and the initializer is a braced-init-list (8.5.4), the program is ill-formed. **Otherwise, obtain P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with** either a new invented type template parameter U or, **if the initializer is a braced-init-list, with std::initializer_- list**. Deduce a value for U using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1), where P is a function template parameter type and the initializer is the corresponding argument. If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, the type deduced for the variable or return type is
> obtained by substituting the deduced U into P.

(emphasis mine).

Scott Meyer has recently presented [a talk](http://vimeo.com/channels/ndc2014/97318797) about this very problem. I'd recommend watching the video.